# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium.

When I try to launch a new driver with below code, I get error. What to do ? I checked the driver version. Its the same as my browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver  
driver = webdriver.Edge()  
driver.get("www.youtube.com")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Suman\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver.get("www.youtube.com")
  File "C:\Users\Suman\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 353, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
  File "C:\Users\Suman\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Suman\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=116.0.1938.69)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF727143DB2+61490]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause:** `get` method expects a fully qualified URL as the argument.

Change this: `driver.get("www.google.com")`

**TO:**

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

With some selenium frameworks, (such as [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)), you don't need to use the full URL:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(browser="edge") as sb:
    sb.open("www.youtube.com")
```

(Use `sb.driver` to access the raw `driver`.)

But for raw selenium `driver.get()`, use the full URL with `http`/`https` included: `https://www.youtube.com`.